# How to change the memory config for the Neo4j-shell command tool of Cypher batch import

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to use neo4j-shell command tool to do Cypher batch import. I followed the instructions described in [Import data into your neo4j database from the neo4j-shell command](https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-shell-tools#import-data-into-your-neo4j-database-from-the-neo4j-shell-command). Here was the command that I ran:

```
import-cypher -d "," -i c://temp//neo//import.csv -o c://temp//neo//out.csv start n=node:employee_idx(EmpID={emp_id}), m=node:permit_idx(PmtID={pmtid}) create n<-[:Assign{AssID:{assid}}]-m
```

If there were only 100000 records in import.csv file, it ran perfectly. But if there were 200000 records in import.csv file, I got error: `Error occurred in server thread; nested exception is: java.lang.OutOfMemory Error: Java heap space`.

How to change the default memory config of this tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the environment variable `JAVA_OPTS` to appropriate values, e.g. on Linux it can be done using

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx4G" bin/neo4j-shell
```